# Writing an UTF8 encoded IPTC tag using exiftool

Tags: encoding, utf-8, exiftool

I am calling Exiftool from my C# app via MedallionShell (console), using UTF8 encoding and I need to write an IPTC field to an image so that it is *internally* UTF8 encoded. However, the string is always stored as an 8-bit Latin2 string in the file.

The commnand line looks like:

```
exiftool.exe -charset UTF8 -charset iptc=utf8 -charset exif=utf8 -City="Říčany" file.jpg
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a workaround: instead of passing the uncidode strings as a command line arguments, pass them in a UTF-8 encoded argument file like this:

```
exiftool -charset utf8 -charset iptc=utf8 -codedcharacterset=utf8 -@ argfile.txt x.jpg
```

and create a UTF-8 encoded textfile `argfile.txt`:

```
 -City=Říčany
```

This works even from a non UTF-8 console. The `-codedcharacterset=utf8` argument is not needed for encoding but it marks the file as an UTF-8 encoded file for future processing.

Comment: Another option would be to HTML encode the problematic characters and use exiftool's [-E (escapeHTML) option](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#E--ex--escapeHTML--escapeXML).  For example `-E -City="&#x158;&#xED;&#x10D;any"`